# how to ignore nonused space from word like "Test - Text" while building html tags

Tags: javascript, html, html-entities

I am forming a tag like this 
    `"<a href=instruction=name,value=" + sParameter +">"</a>"`

But i am expecting some text separated by space Like "Test - Text" in place of sParameter. When a word like this is coming in place of sParameter its displaying the first part means before "-"(hyphan). But when i am getting a word like "Test-Text" its dispalying full word correctly. Can anyone help me in displaying this type of words( "Test - Text").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change space to URLEncoded equivalent (which is %20).

Meaning, sParameter = `Test%20-%20Text`

Comment: how can i change the same,my question is that only , because sParameter i am getting from a dropdown selection. So is there any way that i can change "Test - Text" in the format u have shown.

Comment: @SQLBeginner Yes, the solution for PHP would be [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode), the one for JavaScript would be [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [`urllib.urlencode()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) for Python. Many programming/scripting languages have a similar function.